# How to associate more than one user to a post?

Tags: plugins, users

I have a website we're building with 1600 'Business Listings' which are made as custom post types.
Our problem is that, while there only needs to be one 'editor' of each post/company, there are sometimes more than one user(employees) associated with the post/company.

The biggest reason for this is grouping users with certain businesses, which in turn gets used for email newsletters, and just overall contact info (only seen in the backend by the admins).

SO. Is there a way to associate more than one user to a post? Basically out client wants to be able to go into a company's profile (aka custom post) and see all of the employees attached to that company.

Thoughts? Multiple author-to-post plugin or hack we can do?

Comment: Googling `wordpress multiple authors per post` led me to http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/allow-multiple-authors-to-be-associated-with-a-post-in-wordpress/ Is there anything there you can use? (Linked from that post is the [Co-Authors plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors/).)

Comment: http://txfx.net/wordpress-plugins/multiple-authors/ this plugin works well

Comment: Since you're building a company directory and want to list all their employees, I don't think you want them to be WordPress users. Instead, use a custom post type for employees and map them with the [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin. This way you can associate x employees with a specific company.

Note: The plugin basically also supports multiple authors, using posts-users relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless all these employees will need to login to Wordpress, it may make much more sense to implement employees as a custom post type (a.k.a. CPT).  Once they are defined as a CPT, you then associate wach employee with a company.

As @swisspedy mentioned in his comment, one way to do this is with the [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin.  While a fan of Posts 2 Posts myself, the fact that it requires [editing code](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Basic-usage) to define these relationships may not be desired.  The [Types](http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) plugin enables you to manage CPT relationships from the Dashboard, but it's featureset leaves something to be desired.

Once you set up the employee CPT (in the code, via the Types plugin or some other method), you need to define the relationship between the business and employee CPTs.  I have found [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to have a robust features and a very user-friendly interface.  It will not only help you define the relationship, but it will let you customize how/where the employee selector appears on the 'Edit Business' screen. (On the other hand, the Types plugin lets you create Employees on-the-fly from the 'Edit Business' screen, just by entering the employee name).

Here is an example of code you would place in `functions.php` to accomplish this with the Posts 2 Posts plugin:

```
// Create business/employee relationship
add_action( 'p2p_init', 'register_p2p_connections' );
function register_p2p_connections(){
    p2p_register_connection_type(
        array(
             'name'           => 'business_to_employee',
             'from'           => 'business',
             'to'             => 'employee',
             'title'          => array(
                 'from' => 'Employees',
                 'to'   => 'Employer'
             ),
             'admin_column'   => 'to',
             'admin_dropdown' => 'to',
             'fields'         => array(
                 'title' => array(
                     'title'   => 'Position',
                     'default' => ''
    ))));
}

// Auto-publish posts created via P2P box are drafts (they default as drafts).
add_filter( 'p2p_new_post_args', 'p2p_published_by_default', 10, 2 );
function p2p_published_by_default( $args, $ctype ) {
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
    return $args;
}
```

To list the employees when viewing a business post, in the `single-business.php` template, you add some code like this:

```
// Find connected employee
$connected = new WP_Query( array(
  'connected_type' => 'business_to_employee',
  'connected_items' => get_queried_object(),
  'nopaging' => true,
) );
// Display connected employees
if ( $connected->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <h3>Employees:</h3>
    <ul>
    <?php while ( $connected->have_posts() ) : $connected->the_post(); ?>
        <li><?php 
        the_title();
        $position = p2p_get_meta( $post->p2p_id, 'position', true ); 
        echo ( empty($position) ? '' : ", $position" );
        ?></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul><?php 
endif;
// Restore original (business) post data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Making them into custom post types definitely came out to be the best answer, then using that Posts 2 Posts plugin to associate them. I've looked into that plugin's code and yes needs some decent editing. I now need to figure out how to show associated post types in the admin editor page...

Comment: @Aaron some of my code from a past project might help you.  I've updated my answer to include it.